# String timestamp performance in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongo [4.0.9] which stores document like below

```
{ "_id" : 187489726, "mykey" : { "data" : [ { "id" : 2, "value" : "No" } ], "timestamp" : "2020-06-03 10:40:52.718" } }
```

If I fire queries like so, would it have performance impact because timestamp is string in the collection.

```
db.mycollection.find({"mykey.timestamp" : {$get : "2020-06-05 10:00:10.269"}},{"mykey": 1}).count()
```

I would have close 20 million records in DB.

Could not find any benchmark or documentation such a scenario. I can still convert all in ISO format.

Comment: Test it and find out.

Comment: I think it's better to store the time as milliseconds. The Mongo will query and order faster than a string.

You can get the miliseconds by: (new Date()).getTime()

Comment: The performance is affected by few aspects. First, is having an index on the query filter field ("mykey.timestamp") will improve the performance. Second, the query is likely to be faster if the data "mykey.timestamp" is of a [Date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) object.